# Showing that Lebesgue measure is preserved by translations of the $d$-dimensional torus

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

> Let $\underline{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Show that the transformation $R_{\underline{\alpha}}=\mathbb{T}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{T}^d$ defined by
>
> $R_{\underline{\alpha}}=(x_1 + \alpha_1 \mod \ 1, \dots, x_d + \alpha_d \mod \ 1 ) $
>
> preserves the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on Borel sets $\mathcal{B}$.

Not really sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Lebesgue measure was defined on ${\mathbb T}^d$ in your case. I shall adopt a pedestrian version in the following. It will be sufficient to consider the case $d=1$. Any subset $X\subset{\mathbb T}$ has a representant $\hat X$ in the fundamental domain $[0,1[\ $, and one puts $$\lambda(X):=\mu(\hat X)\ ,$$ where  $\mu$ is the usual Lebesgue measure on ${\mathbb R}$.

For given $\sigma\in{\mathbb R}\ $ denote by $T_\sigma$ the shift $x\mapsto x+\sigma$ $\>(x\in{\mathbb R})$. Note that $\mu\bigl(T_\sigma(A)\bigr)=\mu(A)$ for any measurable set $A$.

Assume that an $\alpha\in[0,1[\ $ is given.  Then the sets
$$X':=\hat X\cap[0,1-\alpha[\ ,\quad X'':=\hat X\cap[1-\alpha,1[\ $$
form a partition of $\hat X$. Let $Y:=R_\alpha(X)$. Then
$$\hat Y=T_\alpha(X')\cup T_{\alpha-1}(X'')\ .$$
The two sets on the right hand side are easily seen to be disjoint. It follows that
$$\eqalign{\mu(\hat Y)&=\mu\bigl(T_\alpha(X')\bigr)+\mu\bigl(T_{\alpha-1}(X'')\bigr)\cr&=\mu(X')+\mu(X'')=\mu(X'\cup X'')\cr &=\mu(\hat X)\ .\cr}$$